# Cannot read CustomAttributes in assembly using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I am having problems reading the `CustomAttributes` of one type.

```
TypeInfo mytype = ...
IEnumerable<CustomAttributeData> customAttributes = null;
try
{
  customAttributes = mytype.CustomAttributes; // Or GetCustomAttributesData
} catch (TypeLoadException e)
{
  // Could not access the attributes
  throw new Exception("Type not loaded for the attribute", e);
}
```

The error I get in `TypeLoadException e` is:

> Could not load type
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ScriptNamespaceAttribute' from
>   assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

The point is that `e.TypeName` has the name of the attribute class that I am using for that type, so the name is actually available!

#### Assembly loaded in reflection only context

I have loaded the assembly by using:

```
Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("Path to my assembly")
```

So I was expecting to be able to access types and read at least their names. It happens with classes and other types, but for custom attributes I have this problem. But if I open the ILDASM (the .NET Disassembler on my assembly). I can see `ScriptNamespaceAttribute` being applied to some of the classes defined in the assemblies.

#### The trick around custom attributes

In [MSDN GetCustomAtrributesData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributesdata(v=vs.110).aspx) I can see this:

> Use this method to examine the custom attributes of code in the reflection-only context, in cases where **the custom attributes themselves are defined in code that is loaded into the reflection-only context**. Methods like Attribute.GetCustomAttributes and MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes cannot be used in such cases, because they create instances of the attributes.

Does it basically mean I have no way to just read the names of these custom attributes? I don't want anything more than that, I just need to know the names of the custom attributes...

#### Question

How can I safely read the custom attributes in an assembly which references types defined externally? I do not need to have the implementation for these classes, **just their names is what I need**.

Comment: What is the exact error message of the `TypeLoadException`? This should work in general, precisely because `MemberInfo.CustomAttributes`/`.GetCustomAttributesData()` was designed for this particular scenario.

Comment: Also worth considering: where reflection can't hack it, [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) probably can. In particular, it's geared toward analyzing assemblies without loading anything at all.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the comments. Well I understand your concerns but as you can see from the doc it seems like for the specific case of custom attributes, they have to be defined in the reflection context. I have updated the question with the error message. About Cecil, I don't really wanna add more dependencies to my project...

Comment: So what's wrong with using `GetCustomAttributesData`? Seems like that should give you exactly what you need without having to create instances of your attribute classes. `CustomAttributeData` has a `AttributeType` property which should allow you to get the name of the class.

Comment: @MattBurland The problem is that it gives the same issue, the same exception. One of the custom attributes defined on the type is not loaded and it does not like it even though I have loaded the assembly by using `ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom`.

Comment: Yes, if the entire *assembly* is unavailable, the reflection APIs won't work -- they still want to give you back full type info. The reflection-only context prevents code from executing, but it's not intended to do full analysis even giving missing dependencies. In this case, you could simply also load the dependency in the reflection-only context, but in general, if you don't know if the assembly is even available, only pure IL metadata inspection will work. There are no framework classes for that; you're going to have to take an extra dependency, whether it's Cecil or something else.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I see your point. I do not understand why custom attributes are so special. For other types the reflection-only context works fine for those types that are referenced but not loaded... That is the odd that I cannot understand

Comment: You're right that in principle, `CustomAttributeData` could be returned that makes at least `AttributeType` available (but might fail if you tried to access, say, `Constructor`), since that doesn't require loading any dependencies. You could always try a [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Please post that as your answer as it is correct. I will check it!